# git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: gitlab

I have a Gitlab repository that contain a number of projects on all of which I can pull and push documents to with Git Bash. I want to set up new project.  On the Gitlab website I have created the new project and am following the usual instructions in Git Bash:

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:new_project_name.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

However when I try push (the last line of the above I get the error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:new_project_name.git'
```

(NB: the project name has been replace in this post by new_project_name)

There is a readme file that is ready to be committed.

I know I've missed something or done something incorrectly but I don't know what. I don't understand why I can push to other projects (the pull/ push is working fine) but not this one. What do I need to do in order to `git push` to the repo?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: I would estimate that I have now repaired some ~100 of your posts that contain all manner of chat and waffle. I expect I have supplied links at various times explaining the site guidelines, asking you again to aim for brevity and technical writing, and asking you to have mercy on volunteer editors, who are stretched too thinly as it is. I reiterate those requests to you again.